# Spring Data / REST - never any contents exposed when hosted on Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I've got a very basic survey app :

- one JPA entity (`Survey.java`)
- one Spring MVC controller (`SurveyController.java`)
- one Spring Data/JPA repository (`SurveyRepository.java`)
- 3 main steps, each matching a specific Validation Group
- a REST API exposed through Spring Data/REST configuration (see `ApiConfiguration.java`)

You can see it live here: http://survey-preprod.cloudfoundry.com/.
The sources are available here: https://github.com/fbiville/spring-example-survey.

Just properly fill the form (3 steps - just answer anything) till you see the "Thanks!" page.
Then proceed: http://survey-preprod.cloudfoundry.com/api/survey and notice there is no contents at all!

This happened will all Spring Data / REST I pushed to Cloud Foundry.
When run locally, there isn't any problems at all.

Is there something I missed?

Thanks in advance,
Rolf

EDIT: even with

`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://survey-preprod.cloudfoundry.com/api/survey`

(so the accept header is properly set), no contents are exposed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys, as (sadly) often, this is a clear PEBKAC instance.

ApiConfiguration was importing CoreConfiguration (which was already loaded once as defined by web.xml). 
Therefore, the same "core" beans were loaded again, but CloudFoundry auto-reconfiguration occurred only the first time on the declared datasource and let the duplicated one as is (that is: an H2 database, of course without any contents).